# how to add gesture in appbar

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement gestures detector in appBar. When user click image or name and it direct to another page. But it display error `Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match. GestureDetector({ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Try again after fixing the above error(s).`

I was trying many things but I get only errors. I am new in all of that and I would appreciate some help.

This my appBar code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold( 
        appBar: AppBar(
          flexibleSpace: GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginPage.routeName);
            },
          
        title: Row(
          children: [
            const CircleAvatar(
              radius: 20,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  'https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-79AS3zNyDuB420uC-pKTA2w-t500x500.jpg'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'Welcome Back!',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        color: Colors.black87)
                ),
                Text('Guest',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 19,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: Colors.black87
                            )),
              ],
            ),
          ],
          )),
        forceMaterialTransparency: true,
      ),
      body: Container(

      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/header_home.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              filterField(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    );
```

Comment: what are the above errors?

Comment: @MãĴď .. display this error.. `Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match. GestureDetector({ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Try again after fixing the above error(s).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what you need to do. referring to ankushlokhande answer

keep in mind to change these parts to adapt to your code needs

`Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginPage.routeName);`

```
 child: Row(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginPage.routeName);
            },
            child: const CircleAvatar(
              radius: 20,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  'https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-79AS3zNyDuB420uC-pKTA2w-t500x500.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Welcome Back!',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Colors.black87),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginPage.routeName);
                },
                child: Text('Guest',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 19,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: Colors.black87)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    forceMaterialTransparency: true,
  ),
```

Answer (score 3):

`GestureDetector` requires a child Widget to execute, the Gesture behaviour will execute on the child widget.

Whatever widget you want clickable, just wrap with the `GestureDetector` and add **onTap** and other required property.

Basic example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('AppBar title tapped!');
            },
            child: Text('Gesture Detector Example'),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('Container tapped!');
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Tap me!',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give example code..  I am new in Flutter

Comment: Sharing in 5 min

Comment: Added an example